# Error when connecting to MySQL database with Python

Tags: python, mysql, linux, database, ubuntu

I am using a simple python function to connect to a MySQL database.I receive an error saying a variable is referenced before it is assigned, but this would not be the case if the connection had successfully established. Why is the connection failing?

I am using Ubuntu Linux 18.04. I am running xampp 7.3 to host the mySQL and apache servers and am using phpmyadmin to access the database.I am running my code with python 3.

This is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def connect():
    """ Connect to MySQL database """

    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                               database='myDB',
                               user='xxx',
                               password='yyy!')

        if conn.is_connected():
            print('Connected to MySQL database')

    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
connect()
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "01_python-mysql-connect.py", line 23, in <module>
     connect()
  File "01_python-mysql-connect.py", line 19, in connect
     conn.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'conn' referenced before assignment
```

I am expecting a successful connection to the database. I believe something could be wrong with my configurations but don't know where to start in solving the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                           database='myDB',
                           user='xxx',
                           password='yyy!')
```

is failing. So `conn` never gets a value assigned to it. But you have a `try...except...finally` block and in the `finally` clause your code is doing `conn.close()`. But `conn` hasn't been assigned because the statement that was supposed to assign it a value failed. That is why you are seeing the message *local variable 'conn' referenced before assignment*. To discover what is wrong, move the call to `close` out of the `finally` clause and put it before the `except`. You can always move it back later.

Answer (score 1):

If the `mysql.connector.connect()` call fails, `conn` will not be assigned, hence the "referenced before assignment" exception.

This is an ideal use case for the [contextlib.closing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) context manager, I think. Try something like this:

```py
from contextlib import closing

try:
    with closing(mysql.connector.connect(...)) as conn:
        if conn.is_connected():
            print('Connected to MySQL database')

except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

This will cleanly and reliably take care of closing your connection for you.